# Occasional EXC_BAD_ACCESS when assigning value in C id __strong * array

Tags: objective-c, malloc, automatic-ref-counting, exc-bad-access

I'm getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crashes when assigning a value in an `id __strong *` array

Here's the code

```
    id __strong *entries;
    entries = (id __strong *)malloc(sizeof(id) * 20);

    for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {

        entries[j] = @{@"key1" : @"value1",  // Crash
                       @"key2" : @"value2",
                       @"key3" : @"value3"]};
    }

    //...

    free(entries);
```

It does not matter what the value is. Even this:

```
    entries[j] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
```

crashes.

It does not crash on every time, but it happens within a few tries. Crashes happen on assigning a value at index 0, so it is not something that happens half way through a for loop and cutting out the for loop does not fix the crash.

Enabling `NSZombies` stops appears the crash from happening but there is no output complaining about any Zombies. The same happens when using the Zombies Instrument - no crash, no zombie output. Enabling Guard Malloc also seems to stop the crash.

Changing the `__strong` to `__autoreleasing` seems to also stop the crash but is this really the fix for the problem and if so, why?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im Not 100% sure, but shouldn't you use calloc?

```
    entries = (id __strong *)calloc(sizeof(id), 20);
```

Maybe that's the problem because it isn't zero initialised. Before freeing, you need to nil the variables.

Comment: (+1) Yes, that is exactly the problem (I was about to give the same answer). With ARC, the compiler generates code to release a previously assigned value before assigning a new value to `entries[j]`. That crashes if `entries[j]` is not initialized.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Changing `malloc` to `calloc` fixed the problem. Just for interest, do you have any idea on why it did not crash every time?

Comment: Maybe the malloced memory happened to be "fresh" and so contained 0, other times, it didn't.